# Мешает доктайп.

Tags: html, css

При указании на странице пятого доктайпа или стрикт, блок не вытягивается по нужной высоте (указывается в процентах. Вытягивание по ширине работает отлично.). Без доктайпа всё работает отлично. Как лучше поступить?

Comment: ты верстал изначально без доктайпа ?

Comment: Код покажите!

Comment: С <!DOCTYPE html>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, что верстать без доктайпа хорошая идея. Наверняка у вас где-то закралась ошибка в верстке. Возможно, нужно изменить подход. Да и использовать сейчас старые доктайпы тоже не актуально. **HTML5** наступает широким шагом.

Было бы неплохо посмотреть на ваш код

Вот мой вариант оформления, вашего ***CSS***: http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/WvxW7/

Comment: Видел какой - то сайт, на котором можно сорцы CSS и HTML выкладывать.
Не подскажете, какой?

Comment: [jsfiddle][1]

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NyaXA/j83bT/

Comment: у вас очень странное представление о css

Comment: А что с ним не так?

Comment: звездочка - обозначает, обращение ко всем объектам HTML, нельзя ее куда угодно пихать. Да и в 90% случаев хватит задать звездочке *{ padding:0; margin: 0; font-size: 100%; }

Comment: Я обновил пост. То, что надо?

Comment: Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

http://htmlbook.ru/layout

Посмотри здесь варианты макетов.

Comment: Благодарю.